# Add line numbers if certain pattern matched

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file to which I would like to add line numbers selectively. Say the target string begins with INIT "command" where command is a variable text string. I want it to be INIT "linenumber command". The idea is that each INIT line is tagged with a unique id ordered but not necessarily contiguous. That unique id could be its line number. Bonuses (virtually of course!) if the number could be in hex.

**EDIT:**

Sample input

```
#: ../src/app-utils/business-prefs.scm:24
msgid "Counters"
msgstr ""
```

Sample output

```
#: ../src/app-utils/business-prefs.scm:24
msgid "123f>Counters"
msgstr "123f>شمارنده‌ها"
```

The file is filled with thousands of these *msg* couples. The msgid and msgstr tags match thus have to have a same code. With the code below I would run it twice and change the inside parameter. I think I have to change some numbers in the code to adapt it for the sample. I have added ">" just to make it easier to recognize the code from the actual string i.e. some beautification.

Comment: As already mentioned, please provide your input and expected output as example

Comment: Hey! Didn't receive notifications, I thought no response and went on to do editor regex search and hunt ;) but Almost. Well at least I can say belated merry Xmas and on-time happy new year!

Comment: Happy New Year ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want (you didn't provide the requestd examples yet), but here's an attempt to solve it with a small Python script. It reads data from standard input and prints them t standard output, inserting an index number in hexadecimal notation in each line that starts with "INIT ":

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys

i = 0 if len(sys.argv) == 1 else int(sys.argv[1])
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if line.startswith("INIT "):
        print(line[:5] + hex(i)[2:] + line[4:], end="")
        i += 1
    else:
        print(line, end="")
```

I saved the script above as `numberinit.py` and made it executable using `chmod +x numberinit.py`.

You are supposed to run it in one of these two ways:

```
./numberinit.py < INPUTFILE
./numberinit.py STARTINDEX < INPUTFILE
```

`INPUTFILE` is the file you want to read and the optional `STARTINDEX` parameter lets you specify the first index to use, default is 0.

Usage example:

```
$ cat example.txt 
my input file
INIT first
INIT second
stuff in between
INIT third
INIT something longer as fourth

$ ./numberinit.py < example.txt 
my input file
INIT 0 first
INIT 1 second
stuff in between
INIT 2 third
INIT 3 something longer as fourth

$ ./numberinit.py 42 < example.txt 
my input file
INIT 2a first
INIT 2b second
stuff in between
INIT 2c third
INIT 2d something longer as fourth
```

You can of course redirect the output of the command to save it in a different file, but don't use the same input and output file (will truncate the file due to how your shell handles redirections):

```
./numberinit.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: One step in the right direction. I have updated the question with a sample but I think it works fine if I only change that INIT to something I should. But would you do a favor and make those length items parameter independent so that you only have to change INIT and no numbers?

Comment: That required some modification but worked! GOF (meaning good enough)